# how to show the image in root directory file(wampserver)

Tags: php

The main problem is when I upload the image. Image is not getting stored in upload folder but remaining fields are successfully inserted in the database. I don't want to image to be stored in database. I want to store it in the upload folder.

This is image upload code in php

[image: 1]

This is htmform code both are in wrote one page

[image: 2]

Comment: make sure the uploads folder is permissioned to 0777

Comment: Is your image upload code in the script your calling on that page? I see them as different names.

Comment: Can you paste your code in the question or paste it on some free online paste website? It's kind of hard to look at code in pictures

Comment: Have you bothered checking what `move_uploaded_file()` returned? If it's false, then the move failed. As is, your code is **HIGHLY** dangerous and allows a malicious user to scribble a file ANYWHERE on your server that they want. You should NOT be trying to do file uploads in php until you've learned how to handle them securely.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure the folder **upload** exists in the same directory as the file **register.php**" and has correct permissions (try **777** for instance).
- Check if the **move_uploaded_file()** is actually called or not.
- Make sure that **move_uploaded_file()** returns TRUE, try:

  echo move_uploaded_files($file_tmp, "upload/" . $file_name);